# I am having problems creating a Lift object with an error saying something about my constructor in my lift class

Tags: java, class, object

i seem to not be able to find why I am not able to create a new lift object.
This is my Lift class as follows :

```
public class Lift {
private int liftID;
private int People;
private boolean availability;

public Lift(int liftID, int People, boolean availability) {
    this.liftID = liftID;
    this.People = People;
    this.availability = availability;
}

public int getLiftID() {
    return liftID;
}

public int getPeople() {
    return People;
}

public boolean getAvailability(){
    return availability;
}

public boolean isAvailability() {
    return availability;
}
```

And this is my main class :

```
Lift l1 = new Lift();
Lift l2 = new Lift();
Lift l3 = new Lift();
Lift l4 = new Lift();
```

I cant seem to be able to create any Lift objects, hope that someone can help me out

Comment: What???? Your code there is creating 4. Do you have an error message?

Comment: proof-read your question after you post it. The code you posted is incomplete at the very least, and taken at face value has no errors  other than that you're calling the constructor without the required arguments (you wrote a three-argument constructor, so you can't call it without any args)

Comment: Be sure to include error messages next time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because your constructor has 3 arguments

```
public Lift(int liftID, int People, boolean availability)
```

so while creating the object you should pass 3 arguments.

Change this

```
Lift l1 = new Lift();
```

To something like

```
Lift l1 = new Lift(arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

You can do it in another way by creating another constructor without arguments.

```
public Lift() {
    //some code or keep it empty
}
```

After that you can create `List` object like you did.

```
Lift l1 = new Lift();
```